# Using a Map<String, String[]> as @RequestParam in Spring with csv notation

Tags: spring, rest, request

Since one of my endpoints is getting more and more parameters i would like to convert noting down every parameter on its own into using a map. The parameters themselves consist of a two element array of values.

As an example:

Call: `getstuff?param1=value1,gt&param2=value2,eq`

Current Method: `getStuff(@RequestParam String[] param1, @RequestParam String[] param2)`

What i want: `getStuff(@RequestParam Map<String, String[]> params)`

If i do this, the String[] will only ever contain one String, and not be split on the comma into two values.

How can i achieve that it works the same as with the explicit parameters, preferrably without parsing things myself?

Comment: create a custom converter for this type